# How to check 3D coordinates against 3D bounding box in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I would have imagined the obvious query was:

```
postgres=# SELECT ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT( 1 2 3 )' ) &&&
                  'BOX3D( -5 -5 -5, 5 5 5 )'::box3d;
```

But this results in

```
 ?column?
----------
 f
```

As opposed to  `t`.

The query seems to lose the z-coordinate from the bounding box completely. This also results in the following issue where a bounding box ranging from z=1 to z=2 will return `t` for a point at z=0:

```
galaxymap=# SELECT ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT( 0 0 0 )' ) &&&
                   'BOX3D( -1 -1 1, 1 1 2 )'::box3d;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of googling I finally happened upon an [e-mail conversation](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2016-February/025626.html) on the postgis-devel mailing list.

> Our boxes are all broken.
>   There should be somewhere a wiki page or ticker or something about
>   options to improve the situation.

The suggested workaround seems to be using lines (or bounding diagonals, which I didn't try):

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint( 1, 2, 3 ) &&& ST_MakeLine(
           ST_MakePoint( -10, -10, -10 ), ST_MakePoint( 10, 10, 10 ) );
 ?column?
----------
 t
```